# Enable 'passive' property in WiX Bundle by default

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX Bootstrapper that invokes MSI. If I launch it as:

`setup.exe`

It will show a UI and user must process with the installation manually. However, if user passes `passive` property, the installation will begin automatically. Uninstallation can also be done silently (no UI interaction required) with:

`setup.exe -uninstall -passive`

What I want is to enable `passive`-ness  by default. I have tried using `Variable` in `Bundle` as:

```
<Variable Name="passive" Type="string" Value="true"/>
```

But doesn't have any effect (even with `value` set to "1", or "yes").

Further, I have tried to set MSI property in Chain->MsiPackage:

```
<MsiProperty Name="passive" Value="1"/>
```

It doesn't make the installation passive by default.

What could be done?

I am using `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense` UI mode.

Comment: Why do you specify a UI mode if you don't want it be shown to the user?

Comment: @harper I don't want to show UI to the user either. So, I may pass `quiet` property as well, and I don't know how to make it default (enabled).

Answer (score 2):

`passive` isn't a property; it's a switch. WixStandardBootstrapperApplication does not support passive UI by default. You'd have to write your own bootstrapper application to do that.

Comment: Okay, then how to write bootstrapper application? First MSI, then custom DLL, then bootstrapper and now bootstrapper app. Too much PITA!